# Draw Growing Stacks of Boxes

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

## The Task

In this challenge, your task is to draw an ASCII art representation of several stacks of boxes of increasing height.
You are given as input the number of stacks, which is a positive integer.
The first stack contains one box of size `2x2`.
The second stack contains 2 boxes of size `3x3`.
In general, the `k`th stack contains `k` boxes of size `(k+1)x(k+1)`.

The borders of each box are drawn using the characters `-|+`, and their interior consists of whitespace.
Adjacent boxes share their borders, and corners should always be drawn with `+`, even when they are part of a border of another box.

## Examples

Output for `1`:

```
++
++
```

Output for `2`:

```
 +-+
 | |
 +-+
++ |
++-+
```

Output for `3`:

```
   +--+
   |  |
   |  |
   +--+
   |  |
 +-+  |
 | +--+
 +-+  |
++ |  |
++-+--+
```

Output for `5`:

```
          +----+
          |    |
          |    |
          |    |
          |    |
          +----+
          |    |
          |    |
          |    |
      +---+    |
      |   +----+
      |   |    |
      |   |    |
      +---+    |
      |   |    |
      |   +----+
   +--+   |    |
   |  +---+    |
   |  |   |    |
   +--+   |    |
   |  |   +----+
 +-+  +---+    |
 | +--+   |    |
 +-+  |   |    |
++ |  |   |    |
++-+--+---+----+
```

## Rules and Scoring

The input can be received from STDIN, as a command line argument, or as a function argument.
Output **must** go to STDOUT or closest equivalent.
Any finite amount of trailing whitespace is allowed, as are preceding and trailing newlines, but there cannot be any extra preceding spaces.

This is code-golf, so the lowest byte count wins.
Standard loopholes are disallowed.

Comment: I think this ascii output is a good illustration for how `n` and `n-1` are relatively prime. Two pluses will never overlap.

Comment: Is there any maximum limit for the input number?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Only the maximum limit of your language's native integer type.

Comment: It seems that this is quite a limiting factor. Some of the submissions will not work for `Integer.MaxValue` as input.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Oh, you're right of course... it was not my intention to invalidate existing answers. Let's overrule that: a solution should work for all inputs for which the total number of required characters in the output does not exceed `Integer.MaxValue` or equivalent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## CJam, <s>64 60</s> 58 bytes

```
]ri:X{'|'}{I))*\I**XX*)Se[s}:L~:M.e>S'-LaI*~M}fI]zN*'}/'+*
```

Constructing each column at a time.

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%5Dri%3AX%7B'%7C'%7D%7BI))*%5CI**XX*)Se%5Bs%7D%3AL~%3AM.e%3ES'-LaI*~M%7DfI%5DzN*'%7D%2F'%2B*&input=5)

Answer (score 8):

## Java (<s>407</s> 349 chars)

*A few chars thanks to @Zgarb and @Geobits*

**Code**

```
void s(int q){int d,h,y,i,j,x,z,t=q*q+1;char b;for(i=0;i<t;i++){z=x=0;d=t-i;for(j=0;j<(q*q+q)/2+1;j++){b=' ';h=x*x+1;if(x==z){y=x+1;if((d<=h&d%(x==0?1:x)==(x==1?0:1))|(y<=q&d<=y*y+1&d%(y==0?1:y)==(y==1?0:1)))b='+';else if(d<=h|y<=q&d<=y*y+1)b='|';x++;z=1;}else{if(d<=h&d%(x==0?1:x)==(x==1?0:1))b='-';z++;}System.out.print(b);}System.out.println();}}
```

Not sure if this is optimal, but it's my first attempt, I will probably try to put it in a better golfing language later. Any suggestions are welcome!

**Expanded**

```
class StackingBlocks{
    public static void main(String[]a){
        int d,h,y,i,j,x,z,t,q=10;
        t=q*q+1;
        char b;
        for(i=0;i<t;i++){
            z=x=0;
            d=t-i;
            for(j=0;j<(q*q+q)/2+1;j++){
                b=' ';
                h=x*x+1;
                if(x==z){
                    y=x+1;
                    if((d<=h&d%(x==0?1:x)==(x==1?0:1))|(y<=q&d<=y*y+1&d%(y==0?1:y)==(y==1?0:1)))
                        b='+';
                    else if(d<=h|y<=q&d<=y*y+1)
                        b='|';
                    x++;
                    z=1;
                }else{
                    if(d<=h&d%(x==0?1:x)==(x==1?0:1))
                        b='-';
                    z++;
                }
                System.out.print(b);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

[Check it out here.](http://ideone.com/3xDr4j)

Comment: Quick tips for 10 bytes: 1) Replace `&&` and `||` with `&` and `|`. 2) Move `int` declarations into the `for` (`for(int i=0,j,x,z;...`). 3) You have one too many braces at the end of your golfed function.

Comment: You have a lot of comparisons of the form `a+1<=b+1`; they can be replaced by `a<=b`.

Comment: `q*q+1` should probably just be assigned to another variable. You use it 9 times or so, and you could save a bunch by saying `a=q*q+1` once. Also, `q*(q+1)` is just `q*q+q`.

Comment: I was just doing that Geobits and Zgarb, thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: You could look for a recursive solution, maybe? It looks like there should be a nice one.

Comment: @mbomb007 I'm not sure how I would do that while printing, or do you suggest I save it during each step and print at the end?

Comment: I'm going to do that anyway, with the iterative approach I'm taking.

Comment: Okay, cool. Looking forward to seeing it

Comment: You can change `(q*q+q)/2` to `q*q+q>>1`

Comment: Due to `t=q*q+1` this does not work for any Integer `q` as input. Unfortunately OP has defined `Integer.MaxValue` as maximum input.

Comment: @ThomasWeller The OP changed that criterion now.

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, <s>144</s> 128 bytes

```py
n=input()
i=n*n
while-~i:j=x=1;l="";exec'y=i%j<1;z=i>j*j;l+=j*z*" "or"|+"[x|y]+" -"[y]*~-j;x=y^z>z;j+=1;'*n;print l+"|+"[x];i-=1
```

Bit twiddling. Bit twiddling everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

## Python, 188 bytes

Mathematically calculates the character at each `x,y` position. It was tricky making the `+`s print on both sides of each box as well as stopping the rightmost `+`s of what would be `n+1`th boxes.

```py
n=input();l=1;c=0
for y in range(n*n,-1,-1):
 s=""
 for x in range((n*n+n)/2+1):k=((8*x+1)**.5+1)/2;i=int(k);b=y<=i**2;s+=" |-+"[((k==i)+2*((y%l+c)*(y%i+(k==n+1))<1))*b];l=i;c=b^1
 print s
```

Comment: what does     (8*x+1)**.5+1  do ?

Comment: @Agawa001 Looks like an [inverse triangle function.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/36008/14215)

Comment: @Geobits Beat me to answering what my own code does!

Comment: @Geobits yea i was thinkin of something like floor$sqrt(2*n-sqrt(2*n))$ ,

Comment: I'm not sure if this works for `sys.maxint` as input value. It seems `n*n` will overflow, or does Python switch to BigInteger then?

Comment: @ThomasWeller python will automatically convert that to a `long` which has *no* upper limit.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Python doesn't have a maximum input value. `sys.maxint` is only there for compatibility purposes, since it's still useful to know that `2**31-1` is the largest value for an integer.

Comment: @mbomb007 not for a BigInteger type

Answer (score 1):

### C# - 304 bytes (function)

```
void b(int s){int h=s*s,w=h+s>>1,x,y,j;var c=new int[w+1,h+1];for(;s>0;s--){for(y=s*s-s;y>=0;y-=s){x=s*s-s>>1;for(j=0;j<s;){c[x+j,y]=c[x+j,y+s]=13;c[x,y+j]=c[x+s,y+j++]=92;}c[x,y]=c[x+s,y]=c[x+s,y+s]=c[x,y+s]=11;}}for(y=h;y>=0;y--){for(x=0;x<=w;x++)Console.Write((char)(32+c[x,y]));Console.WriteLine();}}
```

or 363 bytes (full code)

```
namespace System{class C{static void Main(string[]a){int s=int.Parse(a[0]),h=s*s,w=h+s>>1,x,y,j;var c=new int[w+1,h+1];for(;s>0;s--){for(y=s*s-s;y>=0;y-=s){x=s*s-s>>1;for(j=0;j<s;){c[x+j,y]=c[x+j,y+s]=13;c[x,y+j]=c[x+s,y+j++]=92;}c[x,y]=c[x+s,y]=c[x+s,y+s]=c[x,y+s]=11;}}for(y=h;y>=0;y--){for(x=0;x<=w;x++)Console.Write((char)(32+c[x,y]));Console.WriteLine();}}}}
```

I tried to avoid if statements. Ungolfed:

```
namespace N
{
    public class Explained
    {
        static void boxes(string[] args)
        {
            int size = int.Parse(args[0]);
            int height = size * size + 1;
            int width = size * (size + 1) / 2 + 1;
            var canvas = new int[width, height];
            for (; size > 0; size--)
                drawboxes(size, canvas);

            for (int y = height - 1; y >= 0; y--)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                    Console.Write((char)(32 + canvas[x, y]));
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        static void drawboxes(int size, int[,] canvas)
        {
            int x = size * (size - 1) / 2;
            for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                drawbox(x, i * size, size, canvas);
            }
        }

        static void drawbox(int x, int y, int size, int[,] canvas)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                canvas[x + i, y] = 13; // +32 = '-'
                canvas[x + i, y + size] = 13;
                canvas[x, y + i] = 92; // +32 = '|'
                canvas[x + size, y + i] = 92;
            }
            canvas[x, y] = 11; // +32 = '+'
            canvas[x + size, y] = 11;
            canvas[x + size, y + size] = 11;
            canvas[x, y + size] = 11;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My solution does not work for any input of Integer range as defined by OP. I'd need to use `long` instead.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <s>294</s> 290

I got it working, but I still need to golf it more. I'm so happy, though, that was tough (for me, at least)!

I'll probably add an explanation later, unless it's immediately clear to someone...? I kind of doubt it.

[**Try it here**](http://ideone.com/opaUt4)

```python
n=input()
w=n*n+n+2>>1
a=eval(`[[' ']*w]*-~n**2`)
r=range
j=[i*i+i>>1for i in r(n+1)]
p=0
for i in r(w):
 if i in j:
    p+=p<n
    for k in r(p*p+1):a[~k][i]='+'if k%p<1or' '<a[~k][i-1]<'.'else'|'
 else:
    for k in r(p*p+1):a[~k][i]=' 'if k%p else'-'
print'\n'.join(''.join(i)for i in a)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby (205 bytes)

Takes the number as a command line arguments. It starts with a fail leading newlines, but that's allowed.

```
n=$*[0].to_i
m=n+1
f=m.times.inject(:+)+1
c=((" "*f+p=?+)*n*m).split p
y=0
1.upto(n){|b|(b*b+1).times{|x|d=x%b==0;r=c[x]
d&&b.times{|g|r[y+g]=?-}
r[y]=d||r[y]==p ?p:?|
r[y+b]=d ?p:?|}
y+=b}
puts c.reverse
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 293 bytes

```
(n,o='',r,f,t,u,b,c,e=n*n+1,i)=>{for(t=0;e>t;t++){for(c=b=0,d=e-t,u=0;(n*n+n)/2+1>u;u++)i=" ",r=b*b+1,b==c?(f=b+1,d<=r&d%(0==b?1:b)==(1==b?0:1)|n>=f&d<=f*f+1&d%(0==f?1:f)==(1==f?0:1)?i="+":d<=r|n>=f&d<=f*f+1&&(i="|"),b++,c=1):(d<=r&d%(0==b?1:b)==(1==b?0:1)&&(i="-"),c++),o+=i;o+="\n"}return o}
```

I ran this in Firefox. Ignore the `"` the console adds between the strings. This is mostly ES5 stuff but I'll try to golf this more.

Ungolfed / ES5

```js
function box(n, o, r, f, t, u, b, c, e, i) {
  if (o === undefined) o = "";
  if (e === undefined) e = n * n + 1;
  return (function() {
    for (t = 0; e > t; t++) {
      for (c = b = 0, d = e - t, u = 0;
        (n * n + n) / 2 + 1 > u; u++) i = " ", r = b * b + 1, b == c ? (f = b + 1, d <= r & d % (0 == b ? 1 : b) == (1 == b ? 0 : 1) | n >= f & d <= f * f + 1 & d % (0 == f ? 1 : f) == (1 == f ? 0 : 1) ? i = "+" : d <= r | n >= f & d <= f * f + 1 && (i = "|"), b++, c = 1) : (d <= r & d % (0 == b ? 1 : b) == (1 == b ? 0 : 1) && (i = "-"), c++), o += i;
      o += "\n";
    }
    return o;
  })();
}

document.getElementById('g').onclick = function(){ document.getElementById('o').innerHTML = box(+document.getElementById('v').value) };
```

```html
<input id="v"><button id="g">Run</button><pre id="o"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python - 243 bytes

Generates all the columns, replacing the overlaps on columns except the first one. Then it pads with spaces, transposes, and prints.

```
Q=input()
Y=[]
for i in range(Q):
    f="+"+i*"-"+"+";x=map(list,zip(*([f]+["|"+" "*i+"|"]*i)*(i+1)+[f]))
    if i:y=Y.pop();x[0][-len(y):]=y
    Y+=x
print"\n".join("".join(i)for i in zip(*["".join(j[::-1]).ljust(Q*Q+1," ")for j in Y])[::-1])
```

I am considering translating to Pyth, but I will need a replacement for the pad function.